# In dojo datagrid on rowclick , how to get the next row in HTML

Tags: datagrid, dojo, onclick, row

Hi I have a dojo Data Grid, which is built from ItemReadStore.

OnClick of the first column, I have to hide or show the next 3 rows.

I have to the current selected row using this code:

```
    dojo.connect(pipelineVelocityUI.pipelineGrid, "onRowClick", function (event) {
        var selectedRow = pipelineVelocityUI.pipelineGrid.selection.getSelected();
   });
```

Also, can you please tell me how to add a class to a grid Row.

Can anyone please help me!!
Thanks in advance!